# enable_ip_masquerade and WSL2 Bridge

Tags: docker, networking, wsl-2

I'm using Docker in WSL2 on my Windows machine.
I have problems connecting to a docker image (for example if I launch a docker image from a PostGres database, I can't connect to it from a client on my windows), and similarly way, I'm having trouble building a python image that needs to look for dependencies or if I log into a shell of my docker image, an "apt get update" won't work. In short, my docker images don't seem to be able to connect to the network of my windows machine and vice versa.
If I look at the list of my networks:

```
    docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "0b6e2f8d7966d6910cd99e8225c673576e8e07d0838e21efe23041b4779c59d6",
        "Created": "2022-04-11T08:49:02.8718184+02:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "7aef4a3f6b81abb00da33e86a3320b5c506f19818fc603913a7b2bed94777ef4": {
                "Name": "portainer",
                "EndpointID": "56f9990dbab6a6b78f4a618c55662f6396504552fe942336413d05d9289ab9f5",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "false",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

If I understood the documentation correctly, I thought the problem came from the "enable_ip_masquerade" option which should be "true"... But I couldn't find anywhere how to change this value.
Can you confirm/deny that this is the option that needs to be changed? And how to make this change?

Comment: How are you running and trying to connect to the container?  In most situations the IP addresses in the diagnostic output you show aren't usable, and you pretty much never need to look them up.

Comment: I try to connect to the container by "localhost:port" (to connect to a postgres container, i try to connect to localhost:5432 into the dbeaver client), and if I try to launch a shell in the container and access to the internet, I can't too :

Comment: rousseaua@PRT2507:/mnt/c/Users/axel$ docker run --name ubuntu_bash --rm -i -t ubuntu bash
root@129e7db1ac28:/# apt update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

Comment: Running `apt` in an interactive shell doesn't seem like a programming-related question.  [unix.se] might be a better place to ask.